# Prevent page scroll in angular model update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll

I had a simply interval to refresh my model in angular:

```
$interval(function(){
        ItemsData.getItemsData().then(function(data){
            $scope.items = data;
        });
    }, 1000);
```

data is getted from json api. And elements are added to page by ng-repeat.
But on each second the page scroll to the top. My question is: how to prevent it.

Comment: See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mIVMizjAVjYr9DEEVBkP?p=preview). It is not scrolling the page back to the top. Are you clearing the array by any chance?

Comment: Thanks, the solution was replace .then() with .succes()